# "Scrollable" mat dialog with component

Tags: angular, scroll, dialog

All I found about scrolling the dialog is about the overlay, but it is to describe the behavion off the dialog, but I need to scroll the content inside of it that is NOT in the mat-content, for it is an entire component.

To open the dialog I am using:

> const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CadastroPessoaComponent,
>   dialogConfig)

The dialog config is like this:

> dialogConfig.width = '90%';

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try and set the `height` of your `dialogConfig` to your desired dialog height.

It worked for me:

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(CadastroPessoaComponent, {
   height: '300px'
}
```

It will add an overflow if the height of your component content will be higher than 300px.

For the full list of dialog configuration available, check the [MatDialog API](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api).

Comment: wouldnt it be better to have it only scroll if it is beyond the screen height? scroll may not be needed in desktop but will be in mobile devices.

Comment: @chitgoks I am expecting same. did you found any solution. i do not want the wrapper to be fixed. its auto without height and should be scroll if beyond the screen.

Answer (score 3):

In case you, don't know how much height you need to set. You can:

```
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(myComponent, {
      height: '100%'
    })
  }
```

if you want some padding between the dialog and your page borders. You should set height below 100%.

```
  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(myComponent, {
      height: '90%'
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but you can add scroll to mat dialogue box by add scrollStragey into the constructor.

> import { Overlay } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';
> import { AtStages2Component } from 'src/app/analytical-tools/at-stages2/at-stages2.component';
>
> ```
> constructor(private overlay:Overlay)
>
>    openDialog(): void {
> const scrollStrategy = this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition();
> const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AtStages2Component , {
>   data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal },
>   autoFocus: false,
>   scrollStrategy
> });
>
> dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
>   console.log('The dialog was closed');
>   this.animal = result;
> });   }
> ```

Note: It will automatically take as much height as your component needs to but height and width will vary according to the component.

Comment: its not working for me